# isov2 document class - note too deeply nested

Tags: nesting, iso

I am using the isov2 document class and are using four `\note{`s in one clause.

The isov2 documentation says:

NOTE 4 - Similarly, you may get the message!  Too deeply nested - Again, hit `<return>` and processing should continue.  However, the indentation of later lists may not be correct.

How do I rather change this error into a bad style warning, as it should be?

```
\documentclass[wd,a4paper,copyright]{isov2}
\begin{document}
\clause{Resiliant MWE}
\note{one}
\note{two}
\note{three}
\note{four}
\note{five}
\note{six}
\note{one too many}
\sclause{Giving:}

\begin{verbatim}
Clause: 1

! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \note
          {one too many}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.    
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example showing the issue?

Comment: untested as you provide no example but `\makeatletter\def\@toodeep{\ClassWarning{isov2}{list nesting too deep}} \makeatother` probably does what you ask

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\makeatletter\def\@toodeep{\@latex@warning{Isov2 note list nesting too deep}} \makeatother` also throws warning in Overleaf - thanks.  Please post answer.

Comment: @skvery overleaf is unrelated to this error handling, that is just hosting a standard tex distribution so you would get the sam eerror behaviour in any tex system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially using an incorrect markup...

The [class](//ctan.org/pkg/iso) defines a `note` *environment*. While `\newenvironment{note}` does define a `\note` and `\endnote` pair, you're only using the opening command-like form without a accompanying closing (`\endnote`). Since you're not closing the note off properly, your successive calls to `\note` opens up nested lists up until a point where it causes the error (when it's too deeply nested). You should rather use the following setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{isov2}

\begin{document}

\clause{Resiliant MWE}
\begin{note}
  one
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  two
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  three
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  four
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  five
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  six
\end{note}
\begin{note}
  not too many
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

For more on `note`s, see section **6.3.2 Notes** of the [`iso` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/iso).

---

You can change `note` to be usable as a command in the following way:

```
% Copy note environment into oldnote environment
\let\oldnote\note
\let\endoldnote\endnote
% Change \note to take a single argument and pass it to (new) oldnote environment
\renewcommand{\note}[1]{%
  \begin{oldnote}
    #1
  \end{oldnote}%
}
```

Comment: Is there a macro I can use to change `\note` into `\begin{note}` and `\end{note}`.  As I recall the `isov2` documentation uses `\note`, `\anote`, `\example` and `\anexample` as samples in the document.

Comment: @skvery I only see note as an environment in the isov2 documentation, see the link in Werner's answer.  `\note` is already defined as the internal implementation of `\begin{note}` (as happens for all environments) so you can't easily define it with a different syntax.

Comment: @skvery: I've made an addendum to my answer (at the end) where it shows how you can change the `note` environment into a command.